# How to adding rows to a GridView and saving by ASP.NET C#?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I have an existing gridview that show data from my SQL Server,

I am useing gridview to show data from SQL Server and I want to add a button that can add new row when click the button.

How to add new rows when click button in gridview by ASP.NET C#.

myinfo.aspx:

```
    <div class="card-body">
          <div class="table-responsive">
        
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" CssClass="gvStyle gvStyle th " >
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Fname" HeaderText="company" />
                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Faddress" HeaderText="address" />
                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Ftel" HeaderText="telephone" />
                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Contactor" HeaderText="contactor" />
                     
                     <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Category" HeaderText="category" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>

         
        </div>
      </div>
```

myinfo.aspx.cs:

```
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Fname,Faddress,Ftel,Contactor,Category FROM Company", con);
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds);
    con.Close();
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
     cmd.Connection = con;
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

Please if anyone can help me out ..

Comment: To add rows for table on button click you'll need a js

Comment: Using GridView Control, with template column is much more simpler than dynamic HTML.